# JupyterHub on Kubernetes cannot failed to cull user pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I implemented JupyterHub using a Helm chart on a local Kubernetes cluster on VMware virtual machines. I want to cull users after they have been inactive for a while, but it seems not to work.

This error log from the hub pod (pod named `hub-545895f988-vmj2k`) might be related:

```
[W 2023-11-09 01:12:59.125 JupyterHub log:191] 403 GET /hub/api/users?state=[secret] (jupyterhub-idle-culler@127.0.0.1) 6.40ms
[E 231109 01:12:59 ioloop:923] Exception in callback functools.partial(<function cull_idle at 0x7f8cc77975e0>, url='http://localhost:8081/hub/api', api_token='1b66576c8caa43a9ae64cb419f9bf1f0', inactive_limit=3600, cull_users=False, remove_named_servers=False, max_age=0, concurrency=10, ssl_enabled=False, internal_certs_location='internal-ssl', cull_admin_users=True, api_page_size=0)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 921, in _run
        await val
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterhub_idle_culler/__init__.py", line 422, in cull_idle
        async for user in fetch_paginated(req):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterhub_idle_culler/__init__.py", line 135, in fetch_paginated
        response = await resp_future
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterhub_idle_culler/__init__.py", line 117, in fetch
        return await client.fetch(req)
    tornado.httpclient.HTTPClientError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
```

- Kubernetes version 1.23
- Helm JupyterHub chart version 3.1.1
- JupyterHub version 4.0.2

Here is my configuration values in YAML:

```yaml
singleuser:
  storage:
    capacity: 1Gi
    dynamic:
      storageClass: jhub-nas
  extraFiles:
    mountPath: /etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
    data:
      TerminalManager:
        cull_inactive_timeout: 300
        cull_interval: 60
      MappingKernelManager:
        cull_idle_timeout: 300
        cull_interval: 60
        cull_connected: true
        cull_busy: false

hub:
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
  db:
    type: sqlite-pvc
    pvc:
      storage: 10Gi
      storageClassName: jhub-nas
cull:
  enabled: true
  timeout: 300 
  every: 60
```

I installed the release with the following command:

```
helm install jhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub -n jhub-ns --create-namespace --values config.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my project! I use `kubectl cp jupyter-e928cdfb-2d2b2b-2d4441-2dae41-2d5e4f239780ea:/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json tmp.json` and get the jupyter_notebook_config.json file from created container and it seems alright.